# Detect char differences between two strings and return the strings till the end in C#

Tags: c#, string, char, substring, diff

I have 2 strings

```
string a = "I bought a new truck yesterday and it was sick";
string b = "I bought a new car last year and it was awesome. Mom really liked it.";
```

Basically I want to detect that the word `truck` is different from `car` and log the following text in the console exactly as shown:

```
truck yesterday and it was sick
->
car last year and it was awesome. Mom really liked it.
```

I don't care about the difference of chars after the first encounter. I just want to log everything after a char index of a string is not the same of another string's char index.

I keep running into issues like accessing out of range elements while attempting to use for and while statements, not detecting changes, messing up the string by returning random elements etc.

Comment: Please update to show what you have tried so we may perhaps best fix it for you.  Here is a reference which may assist you here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you need culture specific comparisons? Do you need case sensitive comparisons?  Please update with more specifics for clarity.  Perhaps this can assist you here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can compare corresponding characters and find `index` of the first difference.
Then we can compute the rest of the strings

```
string a = "I bought a new";
string b = "I bought a new car last year and it was awesome. Mom really liked it.";

...

int index = Math.Min(a.Length, b.Length);

for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(a.Length, b.Length); ++i)
  if (a[i] != b[i]) {
    index = i;

    break;
  }

string resultA = a.Substring(index);
string resultB = b.Substring(index);

Console.WriteLine(resultA);
Console.WriteLine("->");
Console.WriteLine(resultB);
```

**Output:**

```
truck yesterday and it was sick
->
car last year and it was awesome. Mom really liked it.
```